# C++20: Why can't range adaptors and ranges be combined in one expression?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am looking at the following snippet:

```
std::vector<int> elements{ 1,2,3 };
// this won't compile:
elements
    | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; })
    | std::ranges::for_each([](auto e) {std::cout << e << std::endl; });
// but this compiles:
auto view  = 
elements
    | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; });
std::ranges::for_each(view, [](auto e) {std::cout << e << std::endl; });
```

and I can't see the reason why the combination of the range adaptor (view) and the range algorithm via the pipe operator does not compile. I suppose it has something to do with the type `std::ranges::dangling` that `for_each` seems to be returning as my compiler (msvc 19.29) reports, but I am not sure ...

Comment: Because `for_each` doesn't work on a range adaptor object. You can make a wrapper around it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't range adaptors and ranges be combined in one expression?

They can be. You just did combine them. You used `elements` as a range, and combined it with the range adaptor `std::views::filter`.

`std::ranges::for_each` however is neither a range, nor is it a range adaptor. It is a function (template) that accepts range as an argument. You can keep it in one expression if you really want to, although at the cost of readability in my opinion:

```
std::ranges::for_each(
    elements
      | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; }),
    [](auto e) {std::cout << e << std::endl; }
);
```

Comment: Speaking of readability: wouldn't something like 
`elements
    | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; })
    | std::ranges::for_each([](auto e) {std::cout << e << std::endl; });` 
be the most readable of all versions ? Or put another way: why is there no range adaptor that takes a range of values and produces a side-effect like printing them ?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't really any inherent design reason why some sets of algorithms do have pipe support (views, actions, and `to` - although C++20 only has views so far) and others don't (everything else in `<algorithm>`). Piping into `for_each` makes just as much sense as piping into `filter`, it's just that range-v3 (and, consequently, C++20 Ranges) only did so for some things and not others.

As of now, there is no opt-in mechanism to make something "pipeable" in the Ranges sense (see [P2387](https://wg21.link/p2387) to change that). But once that paper, or some variant of it, gets approved, it would become easy to write  an algorithm adapter that simply makes algorithms pipeable. So that you could do, for instance, this:

```cpp
elements
  | std::views::filter([](auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; })
  | adaptor(std::ranges::for_each)([](auto e) {std::cout << e << std::endl; });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/76zE41rbT) (note that this depends on libstdc++ internals at the moment).

One issue with the library machinery approach to this problem is ambiguity - this relies on deciding that if `f(x, y)` is invokable that the intent is to make it a full call rather than a partial one. It's certainly possible for some algorithms that you may not be able to distinguish between a partial and full call in this sense (which itself may be one motivation for not having them be implicitly pipeable). This is certainly a known problem with some views already (`zip`, `concat`, and `join` taking a delimiter are examples) and is itself one of the motivations for having a language solution to this problem (e.g. [P2011](https://wg21.link/p2011)).

Of course that only affects whether you could write `| some_algo(args...)`, the opt-in mechanism that I'm describing here could just as easily have been spelled `| partial(ranges::for_each, args...)` instead of `| adaptor(ranges::for_each)(args...)`, and then there'd be no ambiguity. It's just a weirder spelling in my opinion, which is why I showed it the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is a range adaptor: it takes a range of values and converts it into a different range of values.

`for_each` is an *operation*. It takes a range of values and does something with it. That "something" does not led to the production of a range of values. So it's not adapting anything; it is consuming the range.

And range adaptor composition is about building ranges, not consuming them. The product of a range composition is always a range.

What you're asking is no different from wondering why you can add one `std::string` to another, but you can't add a `std::string` to an `std::ifstream` to open a file. Opening a file doesn't produce a string; it produces a *file*. Same goes here: performing an arbitrary operation over a range doesn't produce a range.

This is why `ranges::transform` has a range adaptor `views::transform` version: because `transform` conceptually produces a new range of values. `for_each` doesn't produce anything; it merely consumes a range.

Comment: 'And range adaptor composition is about building ranges, not consuming them.' But, in theory, there could be a range adaptor that only consumes, right ? These kinds of adaptors would then always be the last in a composed range adaptor pipeline.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket: It wouldn't be an "adaptor". Yes, you could make the syntax work in some respect, but you wouldn't call it an "adaptor". And in C++, we generally don't perform something you would think of as a processing operation via `|` operators. They're function calls. Operators shouldn't have side effects.